# Solr 4.3 multicore

Tags: java, solr

i am new to solr.i don't know how to use solr in java application  with out using solrj.i need to to do simple task as crud(insert/update/delete etc..).so i google it and find out some usefull code..but i don't know,it going to be work or not.the code is

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://solrHost.com:8983/solr/update/json");
StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"firstName\":\"Bob\",\"lastName\":\"Williams\"}");
input.setContentType("application/json");
postRequest.setEntity(input);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

How to insert a data in multicore.i.e two or more core at a single time

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I & proper names like Java, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the Solr API directly then you then you have to specify which core to use in the URL, in your example the URL would look like this:
`http://solrHost.com:8983/solr/INSERT_CORE_HERE/update/json`
Where "INSERT_CORE_HERE" is the name you have specified in the `solr.xml`.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you brother,now its working,but i have small doubt,now i execute that class and debug it.all the lines are execute successfully,but how to see the data in solr.Wheather the data's are inserted or not.through our application

Comment: how to know,the data's are inserted or not..kindly help me..

Comment: @Kader, what do you mean? if you want to see if the Update was successful, then you can look at the http response you get back, and look for the status code. Of if you mean how you query solr, then you have to do another http request to the select api (`http://solrHost.com:8983/solr/INSERT_CORE_HERE/select?q=SEARCH_CRITERIA`)

Comment: Brother i got this,when i sysout the httpresponse Response  HTTP/1.1 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL.so its not inserted in solr

Comment: @Kader, please update your original question with the actual HTTP call you send to solr, and the response.